# I keep getting NullPointerException on an initilized (as far as I know) object

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

So I'm working on my android app, on a method that is supposed to get data from my views and assign it to my Post's class attributes. The problem is I keep getting NullPointerException on fieldsReader, which I'm using to get the data from the views.

This is the error:

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference**

This is my code:

```
public class NewPostFragment extends Fragment{

    Post post = new Post();
    private NewPostViewModel newPostViewModel;
    static final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    private static final String TAG = NewPostFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_DATE = 200;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_TIME = 201;
    private EditText editText_date;
    private EditText editText_time;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        newPostViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NewPostViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_post, container, false);

        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_new_post);
        newPostViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                //textView.setText(s);
            }

        });

        Button btn1 = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.locationSearchButton);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapsActivity.class);
                ( getActivity()).startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        Button btn2 = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.post_button);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addPostToDatabase(getDataFromFields(v));
            }
        });

        return root;
    }




    public Post getDataFromFields(View root){

        post.setAvailability(true);                                                                 
        //a.setOwner();

        EditText fieldsReader = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.postTitleField);                  
        post.setTitle(fieldsReader.getText().toString()); //ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR

        fieldsReader = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.postDescription);                                     
        post.setDescription(fieldsReader.getText().toString());



        return post;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing button's view to find edittext field that is wrong you should pass root view to find edittext

```
 Button btn2 = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.post_button);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addPostToDatabase(getDataFromFields(root));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. The error disappeared from that row. The problem is the same error appears on the next .getText() now..
fieldsReader = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.postDescription);                                     
post.setDescription(fieldsReader.getText().toString());  //ERROR
Do you have any idea about what might cause it? I can't figure out why, the syntax is the same as in the previous error row..

Comment: i can't figure out further error without any hint or logcat, kindly post logcat error

Comment: So, in the above code, I was getting NullPointerException on: 
`post.setTitle(fieldsReader.getText().toString());` .
I have modified the code the way you told me and the error disappeared from that line and appeared on:
`post.setDescription(fieldsReader.getText().toString());` ..

This would be the stack:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference.

Comment: the code seems nothing wrong or may be your edittext id is wrong otherwise you can post xml here

Comment: you are right. I got the wrong id. sorry for bothering and thank tou very much!